# Netlogo: adding a plant to the wolf sheep stride inheritance

Tags: netlogo

Me and my friends are working on a project for school. 
In which we're basically trying to make a realistic model out of the model of the following link: https://netlogoweb.org/launch#https://netlogoweb.org/assets/modelslib/Sample%20Models/Biology/Unverified/Wolf%20Sheep%20Stride%20Inheritance.nlogo

Our biology teacher had the idea to add a poisonous plant to the model.
But our programming skills aren't good so we do not exactly know what we could do to add this plant. we know that we should probably add the plant to the code as a patch, but apart from that we do not know what we should do.

If there's anyone who could help us, we would be very thankful.

Comment: To get help, you'll need to post a specific question about a specific coding challenge you are facing — not just a broad description of your overall goal. With only the information given, there isn't much we can say besides "Go for it! And when you get stuck, show us your code and explain the exact difficulty you're having in making the next step."

Comment: And if you don't even know what the next step is, that means you're trying to do something too ambitious all at once. Set yourself a much more modest goal, achieve that, then try to make a small improvement. Repeat.